# Java streams group by function

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

```
Class abc{
    int ID;
    String Desc; 
    String notes;
}
```

---

> ```
> ID       DESC     Notes
> 2        One      N1
> 2        Two      N1   
> 2        Three    N1
> 4        One      N11
> 4        Two      N11
> 4        Three    N11
> 4        Four     N11
> 5        One      N2
> ```

I am trying to see output as follows, duplicate records should be grouped by desc.

Output :

> ```
> 2  one/two/three        N1
> 4  one/two/three/four   N11
> 5  one                  N2
> ```

Comment: How the notes field are considered in your output N1 for 2, N2 for 4.?

Comment: no change for Note field. it will be same record as Id field

Comment: not clear what you want to do with the Notes... Why N1 in the first case? Why N2 in the second?

Comment: Sorry I updated the question now.. Its a mistake in question now i updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using streams in the following way. Here I assume that fields is a `List<Field>`. I provided the definition of the `Field` class below.

```java
fields.stream()
        // group by the id field of the object
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Field::getId))
        // it will return a Map<Integer, List<Field>>
        .entrySet()
        // loop through the entries
        .stream()
        // map each entry to the desired format.
        // I am using the same class for this purpose as well, but you might create something else
        .map(entry -> {
            // id can be retrieved from the key of the map
            int id = entry.getKey();
            // we can join the desc fields
            String newDesc = entry.getValue().stream()
                    .map(Field::getDesc)
                    .map(String::toLowerCase)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("/"));
            // notes can be retrieved from the first field of the List<Field> object
            String notes = entry.getValue().get(0).getNotes(); // THIS ASSUMES NOTES ARE THE SAME
            // return new field object.
            return new Field(id, newDesc, notes);
        }).forEach(System.out::println); // print it.
```

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Field {

    private int id;
    private String desc;
    private String notes;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d\t\t%s\t\t%s", id, desc, notes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have observed me trying to quote this too often in review suggestions as well, that `map` operation cam invoke a function as well. Move that logic to a function and then it might make more sense to write it functionally. On the other side, if note and id are supposedly the same, you can groupBy using both of them and downstream the join mapping the description. Little more work, but cleaner imho.

Comment: I know, since it is for demo purposes I do not really try to separate stuff into several functions. But I 100% agree that it would be cleaner.I didn't group by note and id because it wasn't mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Example implementation using Lombok annotations:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
static class Abc {
    private int id;
    private String desc;
    private String notes;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Abc> data = Arrays.asList(
        new Abc(2, "One", "N1"),  new Abc(2, "Two", "N1"),  new Abc(2, "Three", "N1"),
        new Abc(4, "One", "N11"), new Abc(4, "Two", "N11"), new Abc(4, "Three", "N11"),
        new Abc(4, "Four", "N11"), new Abc(5, "One", "N2")
    );

    data.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(x -> new Abc(x.getId(), null, x.notes),
                Collectors.mapping(x -> x.getDesc().toLowerCase(), 
                        Collectors.joining("/"))))
        .entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> {e.getKey().setDesc(e.getValue()); return e.getKey();})
                .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

prints the following output:

```
MyTest.Abc(id=2, desc=one/two/three, notes=N1)
MyTest.Abc(id=4, desc=one/two/three/four, notes=N11)
MyTest.Abc(id=5, desc=one, notes=N2)
```

Comment: without `null` and `equals`(with `hashcode`), one can `Collectors.groupingBy(x -> Arrays.asList(x.getId(), x.getNotes()))` and then in the `entrySet().stream().map(// use e.getKey().get(0)...)`

Answer (score 0):

The below code,

```
 Map<Integer, List<ABC>> collect = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ABC::getID));
```

When i group it by Id,

```
{2=[One, Two, Three], 4=[One, Two, Three, Four], 5=[One]}
```

Comment: you would not get the output as `[One, Two, Three]` in the value using the code shared and the clarification asked in the comments is something that the OP shall provide, based on which you can determine the notes column value.